# Visual Studio Code not suggesting any CSS properties with styled components

Tags: visual-studio-code, styled-components

So my VS Code suddenly stopped suggesting any CSS properties with styled components, it does suggest them if I create .css file. I already tried to google it without any solutions. I have restarted my PC and reinstalled VSC, styled-components and IntelliCode (and I don't have any other extensions related to this). I also did try installing older versions of those. Is there some weird key combination that I could have pressed or maybe some of you have the same problem?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should install this extension from marketplace: [vscode-styled-components](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=diegolincoln.vscode-styled-components)

Remember to add this line to the setting.json:

- Press Ctrl + Shift + P and type: `setting (json)`
- Open setting json
- Add this line: `"emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true,`

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Xafm.png)

Done.

Answer (score 1):

if you use vs code then you need to install the vscode-styled-components extension

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=styled-components.vscode-styled-components

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).